# How to separate Vim themes for LUI and GUI with same general configuration?

Tags: vim, terminal, gvim, gui, themes

I like `twilight` theme for my Vim, but this theme has 2 major versions, [`twilight256.vim`](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3436) dedicated for terminals and [`twilight.vim`](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1677) designed for graphical interfaces.

I just wondering how to separate these skins for Vim's terminal interface apart from graphical interface, but have all general settings for both configuration in one place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `~/.vimrc`, you can check whether the GUI version is running via `:if has('gui_running')`.

Alternatively, configuration that you put into `~/.gvimrc` is only sourced (but at the end!) in GVIM.

What you name "themes" is usually called *colorscheme*, and the variant is selected with the eponymous Ex command. In the general case, you can `:runtime` (or `:source`) those scripts, e.g. inside the `:if` conditional mentioned above.

#### Example

```
if has('gui_running')
    colorscheme twilight
else
    colorscheme twilight256
endif
```

Comment: Can you enrich your post with some real examples?

Comment: You didn't specify how and what you want to configure, so I'm not sure. I've added a basic example that switches the colorscheme itself.